# How to allow .Net Unit Testing to Reference .Net core 2 web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, unit-testing

I have a bit of a problem and I have tried researching it everywhere but I cannot find an answer.

I going to be doing TDD development in Visual studio using MSTesting (Unit Testing .Net). However, I am going to developing a web application running Asp.Net Core 2.

This is where I am having a problem, The Unit testing project is running .NET Framework 4.7.1 meaning I can not reference the web application. **I CAN NOT CHANGE THE FRAMEWORK OF THE WEB APPLICATION.**

Please have a look at these screenshots:

[image: Unit Testing application]

[image: Web Application]

[image: Error Message]

I can not change the framework of the web application and the unit testing cant use Core 2. Please Help Thanks.

Comment: Can you please double check your installation with this guide: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/installing-and-using-net-4-7-x-and-net-core-2-0-and-c-sharp-7-x-with-vs-2017/

Comment: Change target framework of test project to be same as target framework of application you going to test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have a .net core application or a .netstandard library I recommend you to create a MSTest Project that can run on .Net Core.

[image]